# Why doesn't the count() terminal operation print the intermediate steps?

Tags: java, java-stream

As simple as:

```java
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Long x = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> {
      System.out.println(i);
      return i + 4;
    }).count();

    System.out.println(x); // prints '3'
  }
}
```

The `count()` here is used in order to trigger the intermediate operations which include `System.out.println(i)`, but nothing gets printed from inside `map()`. Why is that?

Comment: Can you find the documentation that says the map function needs to be called? This is why you don't use side effects in your streams.

Comment: I get "1, 2, 3, 3" as output.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Probably depends on the compiler / JIT you're running it on. This is due to an optimization.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it’s a well known optimization of the Stream API implementation introduced in Java 9 and *the* canonical example of why programmers should make no assumptions about the evaluation of intermediate operations. Since it was expected that developers get surprised, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count()) even mentions this. No JIT magic involved.

Comment: Well, it makes sense in functional programming (which the Stream API basically implements). However, I can imagine that it still wrong-foot users of Java, which are used to more OO / procedural ways of handling things. Just skipping over methods that introduce side effects is *generally* not how Java works. Or used to work anyway.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes imperative code continues to work as it used to do. The Stream API is specifically for specifying an operation in a functional/declarative way and accepting that there is less control over the evaluation. The problem here is not that the implementation skips over a method with side effects [but that this function has a side effect to begin with](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects). Loops still exists and are neither deprecated nor discouraged; they are still the preferred approach for side effects.

Comment: Uh, that's what I said right? Yes, when using Stream API, assume & use functional programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Streams are *lazy* and *smart*. Since your terminal operation is `count`, which does not care of individual elements, but only of their number, `map` isn't called.
Replace `count` with something that would need to calculate individual elements, like `sum` - and `map` will be called.

```java
Long x = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> {
            System.out.println(i);
            return i + 4;
        })
        .mapToLong(Long::valueOf)
        .sum(); // prints 1 2 3

        System.out.println(x); // prints 18
```

Also a person in comments rightfully reminds you side effects.

Comment: `.filter($->true)`

Answer (score 10):

The javadoc for [count()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count()) has note that:

> An implementation may choose to not execute the stream pipeline (either
> sequentially or in parallel) if it is capable of computing the count
> directly from the stream source. In such cases no source elements will
> be traversed and no intermediate operations will be evaluated.

Comment: That's an update from [jdk8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--)

Comment: @matt this update was introduced with [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--)

Answer (score 1):

Directly calling count actually not helps to run the map. but if we try to call the `toList` and `Size` for the count. seems working for me.

```java
Integer x = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    return i + 4;
                })
                .toList().size();
```

Comment: I guess that this requires a clear DEBUG comment though, because the next programmer may simply use `count()` again, or the compiler may get "smarter" and still skip the `println` statement. That said, if you perform `println` in a *function* a "TODO fix" comment should already be there.